# How to avoid global variable with incrementing function?

Tags: javascript

Here is my self-executing function:

```
var incrementInt = (function() {
    var manyOut = 10;

    if(incInt) {
        incInt+=manyOut;
    } else {
        var incInt = 0;
    }

    return {
        s: incInt,
        m: manyOut
    };
})();
```

I have privatized the variables incInt and manyOut, and tied the variable incrementInt to the returned object.

My goal is to create a function that returns an object where one property is an integer that increments every time that it is called. I would like the incrementing variable to have the most narrow scope possible.

My problem with the solution I have above is that the variable incInt is re-initialized every time the function is called. Due to its scope within the function, the variable is destroyed automatically.

Comment: Every time when what is called?

Comment: Oh! that is a good point. It is only called once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use methods to add and get the variable `incInt`.

```
var incrementInt = (function() {
    var manyOut = 10,
        incInt = 0;

    return {
        add: function() {
            return incInt += manyOut;
        },
        getInt: function() {
            return incInt;
        }
    };

})();


var a = incrementInt;


a.add();
a.add();

a.getInt(); // 20​​​​​​
```

Comment: very good, the other solutions looked promising but thank you for answering the full question of returning an object, and noticing that I wanted the increment to be a variable

Answer (score 1):

You could create and object like this

```
function incr () {
  var i = 0;

  this.inc = function() {
    i++;
  }
}

var incrInt = new incr();

// somewhere in you code
incrInt.inc();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var f = function() { var c=0; return function() { return c++; }} ()
> f()
0
> f()
1
> f()
2
```

Basically, exploit Javascript's ability to use functions to create scope and closures to capture local variables.